# Is there any way to hide/invisible a flow on node-red editor?

Tags: node-red

I am using **node-red editor** and I defined a flow (flow-A) which has some linked nodes.
This (flow-A) is triggered to run when node-red starts.

[image: here my node-red editor with the flow-A]

I want to hide (flow-A) on node-red editor, that means not to show this flow to any user.

Because I want this (flow-A) runs internally. Sometimes, we want somethings runs in background and hide to user.
Is there anyway to do this or make it happen?

Ps: please don't mention about if how I can edit it if it also hide to me (because it is hidden for all user - no exception, assumption I defined it once only)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to hide deployed nodes or flows.

The only way to "hide" this flow would be to run it in a separate instance of Node-RED

The best you can do (in the same instance of Node-RED) is to it put the flow on anther tab in the editor. But if the user has write access to the editor then they will be able to change the flow.